# Drop a marker where clicked and display the co-ordinates and address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm a noob who's written some JS code for google maps and am facing some problems.

What I'm trying to achieve:-

1. When the page loads, it picks up location. Then when I click on  the map, it drops a marker.
2. When I click somewhere else, it drops the SAME marker on a different location now.
3. gets the co-ords of the place and displays it in a text box.
4. Conversely, I add a location in address bar and if it present, it drops a marker to that location and gets co-ords.

Problems I am facing:

1. The map drops a NEW marker everytime I click on the map.
2. Doesn't get co-ords of that location.
3. Does Not search from address.

My limitations:

1. Noob
2. Cannot figure out code to search from address bar.

Please point me in the right direction.

Here's the code

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: 40.731, lng: -73.997}
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
  });
  function placeMarker(latlng, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: map
    });  
    map.panTo(latlng);
  }
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
  });
}
function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
  var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
  var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
  var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
  geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
        map.setZoom(11);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map
        });
        infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        window.alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html, body, #map {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<div id="floating-panel">
  <input id="latlng" type="text" value="40.714224,-73.961452">
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Reverse Geocode">
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the marker in your `initMap` function, then omit its `map` property, which you can add in your click event handler.  Then simply update its position each time.  e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 8,
                center: {lat: 40.731, lng: -73.997}
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: 0, lng: 0}
            });  

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
                placeMarker(e.latLng, map, marker);
            });
        }

        function placeMarker(latlng, map, marker) {
            marker.setPosition(latlng);
            marker.setMap(map);
            map.panTo(latlng);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey @duncan, what this does is that it places the marker there once alright, but when I click on it again, it doesnt update the position of the marker. It should because its inside the click event as you placed it. Confused.

Comment: It works ok for me, possibly something else in your code is causing a problem. I've updated my answer with a working example